# I accidentally deleted the Wifi icon on my desktop. And now I can't find how else to connect to a network. Can you please help?

Tags: networking, wifi, gui

While I was trying to find out how to connect to a network, I accidentally deleted the wifi icon located on the far right of the taskbar. Now that I know how to set up a network I can't find the icon or anywhere else to connect to a network.

Comment: A similar icon should be present in a menu or in `/usr/share/applications`, so you should be able to open it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **LXTerminal**. Type `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove wpagui`, then after the operation ends, type `sudo apt-get install wpagui`.

Simply reinstalling it hopefully will be the solution for you.

But also you can go for creating a brand new shortcut instead of the one you deleted using this guide :

http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/gui/desktop-shortcuts

Another option as Wilf commented, you can copy that similar icon to desktop location from command line using `cp`.

Or you can create a **symbolic link** by typing `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symboliclink`, I think it should also work as a shortcut.

Comment: The icon not being there will likely be set in the local preferences, so reinstalling may not help at all.

Comment: You're right but until he deleted it was there as he said and if deleting it doesn't change preferences it will most likely reappear @Wilf

Answer (score 0):

I did this same thing. I simply right clicked on the panel, selected "Add/Remove Panel Items", clicked "Add" over on the right side, clicked "Wireless & Wired Network", Add.